# Listview with many items is too slow when create

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile-listview

I work on mobile app using and phonegap , the app have JqueryMobile listview with many items 
(more than 20 items **li** ) and every **li** have textbox and 3 radio buttons , when i try to create and refresh listview using this code :

```js
$("#ListView").trigger('create').listview().listview("refresh");
```

It takes 15 second to create the listview .

any one know how i can speed the create of listview with many items?

below handelbar template that i used to populate listview:

```html
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="lstQuestions">
    {{#each Data}}

        <li data-role="fieldcontain"  >
            <label  >{{DOrder}} - {{Title}}</label>

            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"  >
                <input type="radio" name="rdo-{{ID}}" id="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-3" value="3" data-theme="c" />
                <label for="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-3">Nothing</label>

                <input type="radio" name="rdo-{{ID}}" id="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-2" value="2" data-theme="c" />
                <label for="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-2">No</label>

                <input type="radio" name="rdo-{{ID}}" id="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-1" value="1" data-theme="c" />
                <label for="rdo-{{InspectionID}}-{{ID}}-1">Yes</label>

            </fieldset>
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" class="fieldsetClass">
                <label for="txt-{{ID}}">Comment</label>
                <input type="text" id="txt-{{ID}}" name="txt-{{ID}}" value="{{Comment}}"   />
            </fieldset>
        </li>

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Comment: `.trigger('create')` is enough I assume.

Comment: thanks but it's still have the same problem. it's takes too much time to create .

Answer (score 0):

Qudah. 
I'm have been develop app with phonegap an jQuery Mobile. In jQuery Mobile, listview is very very slow. If have many item then ever never use listview. 
Solution: you should rewrite listview and ignore data-role="listview", your app will faster.

```
    <ul>
        <li>
        <li>
    </ul>
    //very faster than
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li>
        <li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: can you provide same example. my list view is very very slow